# Why do I see myself twice when I run the who command?

Tags: shell, users

When I run `who` on my ubuntu laptop I see myself listed twice.  Once with `pts/0` and once with `pts/2`.  Why is that?

Comment: These are different pseudo-terminal devices allocated to the different terminal emulators you have open. `pts/0` actually lives in `/dev/pts/0`.

Answer (score 2):

`who` shows each terminal you are logged in on. Separate terminal emulator windows (gnome-termal, xterm, etc.) and ssh instances are treated as completely separate "pseudo"-terminals, and therefore listed separately. When you ran `who`, you must have had two terminal windows open. If you try it with three, you will see yourself listed three times.